# How to make jquery.searcher search by word instead of complete string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented a [lloiser/jquery-searcher](https://github.com/lloiser/jquery-searcher) in my project. But i just noticed a big flaw in its search function.

Apparently it searches the entire string of what in the text box rather than words. For example if i type "Respect" Aretha Franklin appears but when i search "respect dog" i want both Aretha Franklin and Elvis Presley's Hound Dog to appear.

the reason is because im implementing this search to sift through DVD's, CD-ROMS, Blu-rays etc on my project.

So if someone wants to search Action DVDs it will show all items with Action and DVD in the text. Like how normal searches are.

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/neosketo/6p6w19jL/8/

My HTML:

```
<label>Search for: <input id="cardsearchinput" type="text" /></label>
    <div id="carddata">
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#1</div><div class="title">Like a Rolling Stone</div><div class="artist">Bob Dylan</div><div class="date">1965</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#2</div><div class="title">(I Can't Get No) Satisfaction</div><div class="artist">The Rolling Stones</div><div class="date">1965</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#3</div><div class="title">Imagine</div><div class="artist">John Lennon</div><div class="date">1971</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#4</div><div class="title">What's Going On</div><div class="artist">Marvin Gaye</div><div class="date">1971</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#5</div><div class="title">Respect</div><div class="artist">Aretha Franklin</div><div class="date">1967</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#6</div><div class="title">Good Vibrations</div><div class="artist">The Beach Boys</div><div class="date">1966</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#7</div><div class="title">Johnny B. Goode</div><div class="artist">Chuck Berry</div><div class="date">1958</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#8</div><div class="title">Hey Jude</div><div class="artist">The Beatles</div><div class="date">1968</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#9</div><div class="title">Smells Like Teen Spirit</div><div class="artist">Nirvana</div><div class="date">1991</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#10</div><div class="title">What'd I Say</div><div class="artist">Ray Charles</div><div class="date">1959</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#11</div><div class="title">My Generation</div><div class="artist">The Who</div><div class="date">1965</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#12</div><div class="title">A Change Is Gonna Come</div><div class="artist">Sam Cooke</div><div class="date">1964</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#13</div><div class="title">Yesterday</div><div class="artist">The Beatles</div><div class="date">1965</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#14</div><div class="title">Blowin' in the Wind</div><div class="artist">Bob Dylan</div><div class="date">1963</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#15</div><div class="title">London Calling</div><div class="artist">The Clash</div><div class="date">1980</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#16</div><div class="title">I Want to Hold Your Hand</div><div class="artist">The Beatles</div><div class="date">1963</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#17</div><div class="title">Purple Haze</div><div class="artist">Jimi Hendrix</div><div class="date">1967</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#18</div><div class="title">Maybellene</div><div class="artist">Chuck Berry</div><div class="date">1955</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#19</div><div class="title">Hound Dog</div><div class="artist">Elvis Presley</div><div class="date">1956</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#20</div><div class="title">Let It Be</div><div class="artist">The Beatles</div><div class="date">1970</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#21</div><div class="title">Born to Run</div><div class="artist">Bruce Springsteen</div><div class="date">1975</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#22</div><div class="title">Be My Baby</div><div class="artist">The Ronettes</div><div class="date">1963</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#23</div><div class="title">In My Life</div><div class="artist">The Beatles</div><div class="date">1965</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#24</div><div class="title">People Get Ready</div><div class="artist">The Impressions</div><div class="date">1965</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#25</div><div class="title">God Only Knows</div><div class="artist">The Beach Boys</div><div class="date">1966</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#26</div><div class="title">A Day in the Life</div><div class="artist">The Beatles</div><div class="date">1967</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#27</div><div class="title">Layla</div><div class="artist">Derek and the Dominos</div><div class="date">1970</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#28</div><div class="title">(Sittin' on) the Dock of the Bay</div><div class="artist">Otis Redding</div><div class="date">1968</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#29</div><div class="title">Help!</div><div class="artist">The Beatles</div><div class="date">1965</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#30</div><div class="title">I Walk the Line</div><div class="artist">Johnny Cash</div><div class="date">1956</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#31</div><div class="title">Stairway to Heaven</div><div class="artist">Led Zeppelin</div><div class="date">1971</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#32</div><div class="title">Sympathy for the Devil</div><div class="artist">The Rolling Stones</div><div class="date">1968</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#33</div><div class="title">River Deep, Mountain High</div><div class="artist">Tina Turner</div><div class="date">1966</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#34</div><div class="title">You've Lost That Lovin' Feeling</div><div class="artist">Righteous Brothers</div><div class="date">1964</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#35</div><div class="title">Light My Fire</div><div class="artist">The Doors</div><div class="date">1967</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#36</div><div class="title">One</div><div class="artist">U2</div><div class="date">1991</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#37</div><div class="title">No Woman, No Cry</div><div class="artist">Bob Marley</div><div class="date">1975</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#38</div><div class="title">Gimme Shelter</div><div class="artist">The Rolling Stones</div><div class="date">1969</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#39</div><div class="title">That'll Be the Day</div><div class="artist">Buddy Holly</div><div class="date">1957</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#40</div><div class="title">Dancin' in the Streets</div><div class="artist">Martha and the Vandellas</div><div class="date">1964</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#41</div><div class="title">The Weight</div><div class="artist">The Band</div><div class="date">1968</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#42</div><div class="title">Waterloo Sunset</div><div class="artist">The Kinks</div><div class="date">1968</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#43</div><div class="title">Tutti Frutti</div><div class="artist">Little Richard</div><div class="date">1956</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#44</div><div class="title">Georgia on My Mind</div><div class="artist">Ray Charles</div><div class="date">1960</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#45</div><div class="title">Heartbreak Hotel</div><div class="artist">Elvis Presley</div><div class="date">1956</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#46</div><div class="title">Heroes</div><div class="artist">David Bowie</div><div class="date">1977</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#47</div><div class="title">Bridge Over Troubled Water</div><div class="artist">Simon &amp; Garfunkel</div><div class="date">1970</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#48</div><div class="title">All Along the Watchtower</div><div class="artist">Jimi Hendrix</div><div class="date">1968</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#49</div><div class="title">Hotel California</div><div class="artist">The Eagles</div><div class="date">1976</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#50</div><div class="title">The Tracks of My Tears</div><div class="artist">Smokey Robinson</div><div class="date">1965</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#51</div><div class="title">The Message</div><div class="artist">Grandmaster Flash</div><div class="date">1982</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#52</div><div class="title">When Doves Cry</div><div class="artist">Prince</div><div class="date">1984</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#53</div><div class="title">Anarchy in the U.K.</div><div class="artist">The Sex Pistols</div><div class="date">1977</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#54</div><div class="title">When a Man Loves a Woman</div><div class="artist">Percy Sledge</div><div class="date">1966</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#55</div><div class="title">Louie Louie</div><div class="artist">The Kingsmen</div><div class="date">1963</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#56</div><div class="title">Long Tall Sally</div><div class="artist">Little Richard</div><div class="date">1956</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#57</div><div class="title">A Whiter Shade of Pale</div><div class="artist">Procol Harum</div><div class="date">1967</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#58</div><div class="title">Billie Jean</div><div class="artist">Michael Jackson</div><div class="date">1983</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#59</div><div class="title">The Times They Are A-Changin'</div><div class="artist">Bob Dylan</div><div class="date">1964</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#60</div><div class="title">Let's Stay Together</div><div class="artist">Al Green</div><div class="date">1971</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#61</div><div class="title">Whole Lotta Shakin' Going On</div><div class="artist">Jerry Lee Lewis</div><div class="date">1957</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#62</div><div class="title">Bo Diddley</div><div class="artist">Bo Diddley</div><div class="date">1955</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#63</div><div class="title">For What It's Worth</div><div class="artist">Buffalo Springfield</div><div class="date">1967</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#64</div><div class="title">She Loves You</div><div class="artist">The Beatles</div><div class="date">1963</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#65</div><div class="title">Sunshine of Your Love</div><div class="artist">Cream</div><div class="date">1968</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#66</div><div class="title">Redemption Song</div><div class="artist">Bob Marley</div><div class="date">1980</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#67</div><div class="title">Jailhouse Rock</div><div class="artist">Elvis Presley</div><div class="date">1957</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#68</div><div class="title">Tangled Up in Blue</div><div class="artist">Bob Dylan</div><div class="date">1975</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#69</div><div class="title">Crying</div><div class="artist">Roy Orbison</div><div class="date">1961</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#70</div><div class="title">Walk On By</div><div class="artist">Dionne Warwick</div><div class="date">1964</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#71</div><div class="title">California Girls</div><div class="artist">The Beach Boys</div><div class="date">1965</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#72</div><div class="title">Papa's Got a Brand New Bag</div><div class="artist">James Brown</div><div class="date">1966</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#73</div><div class="title">Summertime Blues</div><div class="artist">Eddie Cochran</div><div class="date">1958</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#74</div><div class="title">Superstition</div><div class="artist">Stevie Wonder</div><div class="date">1972</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#75</div><div class="title">Whole Lotta Love</div><div class="artist">Led Zeppelin</div><div class="date">1969</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#76</div><div class="title">Strawberry Fields Forever</div><div class="artist">The Beatles</div><div class="date">1967</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#77</div><div class="title">Mystery Train</div><div class="artist">Elvis Presley</div><div class="date">1955</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#78</div><div class="title">I Got You (I Feel Good)</div><div class="artist">James Brown</div><div class="date">1965</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#79</div><div class="title">Mr. Tambourine Man</div><div class="artist">The Byrds</div><div class="date">1965</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#80</div><div class="title">I Heard It Through the Grapevine</div><div class="artist">Marvin Gaye</div><div class="date">1968</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#81</div><div class="title">Blueberry Hill</div><div class="artist">Fats Domino</div><div class="date">1956</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#82</div><div class="title">You Really Got Me</div><div class="artist">The Kinks</div><div class="date">1964</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#83</div><div class="title">Norwegian Wood (This Bird Has Flown)</div><div class="artist">The Beatles</div><div class="date">1965</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#84</div><div class="title">Every Breath You Take</div><div class="artist">The Police</div><div class="date">1983</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#85</div><div class="title">Crazy</div><div class="artist">Patsy Cline</div><div class="date">1961</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#86</div><div class="title">Thunder Road</div><div class="artist">Bruce Springsteen</div><div class="date">1975</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#87</div><div class="title">Ring of Fire</div><div class="artist">Johnny Cash</div><div class="date">1963</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#88</div><div class="title">My Girl</div><div class="artist">The Temptations</div><div class="date">1965</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#89</div><div class="title">California Dreamin'</div><div class="artist">The Mamas &amp; The Papas</div><div class="date">1965</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#90</div><div class="title">In the Still of the Night</div><div class="artist">The Five Satins</div><div class="date">1956</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#91</div><div class="title">Suspicious Minds</div><div class="artist">Elvis Presley</div><div class="date">1969</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#92</div><div class="title">Blitzkrieg Bop</div><div class="artist">The Ramones</div><div class="date">1976</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#93</div><div class="title">I Still Haven't Found What I'm Looking For</div><div class="artist">U2</div><div class="date">1987</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#94</div><div class="title">Good Golly, Miss Molly</div><div class="artist">Little Richard</div><div class="date">1958</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#95</div><div class="title">Blue Suede Shoes</div><div class="artist">Carl Perkins</div><div class="date">1956</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#96</div><div class="title">Great Balls of Fire</div><div class="artist">Jerry Lee Lewis</div><div class="date">1957</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#97</div><div class="title">Roll Over Beethoven</div><div class="artist">Chuck Berry</div><div class="date">1956</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#98</div><div class="title">Love and Happiness</div><div class="artist">Al Green</div><div class="date">1972</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#99</div><div class="title">Fortunate Son</div><div class="artist">Creedence Clearwater Revival</div><div class="date">1969</div></div>
        <div class="card"><div class="nr">#100</div><div class="title">You Can't Always Get What You Want</div><div class="artist">Rolling Stones</div><div class="date">1969</div></div>
    </div>
```

My Javascript:

```
    $("#carddata").searcher({
        itemSelector: ".card",
        textSelector: "div",
        inputSelector: "#cardsearchinput",
        highlight: "<span class='highlight'>$1</span>",
        toggle: function(item, containsText) {
            if (containsText)
                $(item).fadeIn();
            else
                $(item).fadeOut();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6p6w19jL/10/

The plugin you are using does not support what you want. But you could acomplish what you want with something like this:

```
$("#cardsearchinput").keyup(function(){
      //If the query is empty show all
      if($(this).val() == ""){
         $(".card").show();
         return;
      }

      //make a array out of the string
      var query = $(this).val().split(" ")

      //loop over all the titles
      $(".title").each(function(){

         var elem = $(this); 
         var count = 0;

         $(query).each(function(key, val){
            //check if the title contains the keyword
            if(elem.html().toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1)
                count++
         })

         //if the title contains any keyword and show it
         if(count > 0){
            return elem.parent().show()
         }

          //hide the element
         return elem.parent().hide()
     });
  })
```

Comment: this works nicely. but its not && the spaced terms together. If i search "good molly" it should only return "Good Golly, Miss Molly" because thats the only item that contains those terms.

Comment: Try and replace the `if(count > 0)` with `if(count == query.length)` is this what you want?

Comment: absolutely amazing!